# what api template can I get the correct JSON object to store in the Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I'm currently doing a project about storing http post urlencoded data from a device and store in Dynamodb. But I can't get the correct object format in the Dynamodb, all I can get is like this

[image: Dynamodb data]

[image: data shown in Dynamodb]

and my lambda function to pass the data is like this:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context,callback) {
  var input = querystring.parse(event.body);
  var inputttt=input.data;
  var params={
    Item:{
      date:Date.now(),
      message:event.body,
      ID:inputttt,
      a:{"id":"123456","data":[{"mac":"1231"}]}
    },    
  TableName:'wifi'
  };
```

Also, my API using the application/x-www-form-urlencoded and the template is

```
{
"body": $input.json('$')
}
```

What I need in the Dynamodb is something like a standard JSON object like this

[image: desired format]

I can't change anything in the client device, all I can change is the uploading URL which is the API endpoint.

Comment: you are doing toString while putting to dynamodb, try converting event.body to a json object.

Comment: @hoangdv I updated the question, you can now see the event.body in message row in the Dynamodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to provide the types if you use the [DocumentClient](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-the-amazon-dynamodb-document-client-in-the-aws-sdk-for-javascript/) API instead of the DynamoDB API.

DocumentClient is an API that abstracts types away when manipulating items into DynamoDB, making it way easier to read and write items from it.

Assuming you're invoking `DynamoDB.putItem(params)` at some point, you'll need to replace it with DocumentClient's API and use its `put` method instead.

Your code will then be as simple as:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    await docClient.put({
        Item: {
            date: Date.now(),
            message: JSON.parse(event.body),
            ID: 'some-random-id-you-choose',
            a: { "id": "123456", "data": [{ "mac": "1231" }] }
        },
        TableName: 'wifi'
    }).promise()
}
```

See that I'm using [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await), so you don't need to use Lambda's callback nor DynamoDB's callbacks anymore.

All API operations for DocumentClient are available on the [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried the code you provided, the thing is when I tried JSON.parse, it occurs an error, nothing is stored in the dynamodb. I used postman to test and it returns {
    "errorMessage": "Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0",
    "errorType": "SyntaxError",
    "stackTrace": [
        "JSON.parse (<anonymous>)",
        "exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:11:27)"
    ]
}

Comment: But that's another problem: that's because your event.body is invalid. How are you testing it?

Comment: If I were you, I'd test the code I have provided without parsing the event.body and putting a random string on its place just to see how to insert items on dynamoDB (which is your problem now). Once you're past this stage, then you can start playing with the event itself.

Comment: OK, I am now able to JSON parse and get the JSON object. But when I try to insert the whole object into Dynamodb, the log shows an error like"errorMessage": "One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string"    So I check my input object and it contains two empty value,"lat": "",  "lon": ""   . It seems the Dynamodb does not accept empty value, any methods to fix with this?

Comment: Also, I try to delete the empty JSON, the input data can be inserted into dynamodb, however, I check the console log and find that after I delete the two empty key and value pairs, All double quotes become single quote, but it is can be mapped in Dynamodb. Not sure if anything wrong.

Comment: You'll have to handle it manually as DynamoDB does not allow empty attributes. I suggest you remove the attribute in case it's empty when putting a new item, e.g `if (myObj.myAttr === '') { delete myObj.myAttr }`

Comment: And I don't understand why you should care about the single/double quotes thing. It's only something you're printing in the console. Data is being stored correctly. You can also retrieve data successfully, so I don't understand your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

While DynamoDB is a schema-less document store, it does require that you declare the type of data that is stored in the fields of the item.

Your code should look like this:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const ddb = new aws.DynamoDB();

const Item = {
    date: {N: Date.now()},
    message: {S: event.body},
    ID: {S: inputttt},
    a: {M: {
        "id":{S: "123456"},
        "data":{L: [ {M: {"mac":{S: "1231"}}} ]}
    }}

};

const TableName = 'wifi';

ddb.putItem({Item, TableName}, (err, data) => { ... })
```

In the code above, every property of `Item` is an object, mapping a type to a value. For example, date is a number type, with `{N: Date.now}`; `a` is an object, or a map, with `{M: {"id" ... }}`, and `id` is a string, with `{S: '123456'}`.

The code above makes some assumptions about the types. You should make sure that the types I chose are correct for your data. (e.g., assumed `event.body` and `inputttt` are strings.)